# Axios hitting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=be2e163d03a0b97a96a89b0230be8e4a&q=klang,my

When I directly paste the URL into the browser, I can make the API request successfully. However, when I try it with `Axios` I'm hitting below exception

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Based on some research, 
I can't understand the logic behind as I'm following the exact same steps provided by online course, by simply firing this API call using Axios should be able to return the result.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'be2e163d03a0b97a96a89b0230be8e4a';
const ROOT_URL = `https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`
export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},my`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

Comment: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/calling-openweathermap-api-is-blocked-due-to-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing/191868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception means the server your hitting does not support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).
In the case of `openweathermap.org` I think you should be using **`api.openweathermap.org`** instead of **`samples.openweathermap.org`**

Comment: You're right, guess I've made the request to the old endpoint which doesnt support CORS. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few things i observed:

1. You are using the **`sample api`**(“samples.openweathermap.org”) not the **`production one`**(“api.openweathermap.org”) so i think for integration with application you should use production API.On this they give the CORS support.
2. If you still want to check with ***sample api endpoint*** then

   The easy way is to just add the extension in google chrome to allow access using CORS.
   (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US)

   Just enable this extension whenever you want allow access to no 'access-control-allow-origin'header request.

   **Or**

   In Windows, paste this command in run window

   chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Reference: https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/16823835-cors

Answer (score 1):

You need to add cors in your server app

```
 var cors = require('cors');
 app.use(cors());
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

When you directly access the url in browser there is no cross domain request is issued.
But when you access the resource using axios there might be a chance that you are accessing resource on different domain then the domain present on your browser tab.That is the reason you are getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin not present. For handling this add a logic on server side to add this header in OPTION Response.

Comment: server side as in `openweathermap.org`'s server?

Comment: I am not aware of what is this but you need to add filter like logic in spring or servlets to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the Response.